# "forceSelection:true" does not let clearing the field

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I set `forceSelection:true` for a combo, the user can not clear it after selectiong an option. Without adding a dummy empty choice, how can I let him to clear the field ?

Answer (score 0):

I add a "clear" trigger to my comboboxes that need this support. Ultimately, you just need an action to hook onto in order to call clearValue().

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    ...
    trigger1Cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
    trigger2Cls: 'x-form-arrow-trigger',

    onTrigger1Click: function() {
        this.clearValue();
    }
});
```

Here's an http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?190886-How-to-reset-a-Combobox-or-Multiselect-to-no-values-selected

*NOTE*: You'll still need to do some CSS and create an image (probably) in order for the trigger image to show up.